# natural isomorphism between $\mbox{Hom}_R(A,\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,B))$ and $\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

let $R$ be a commutative ring, $A$ be a $R$-module and $B$ an abelian group. Then I want to prove that there is a natural isomorphism $$\mbox{Hom}_R(A,\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,B))\cong\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,B)$$

Comment: What is the $R$-module structure of $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(R,B)$?

Comment: What have you tried? To start, can you find a map in either direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the map $\cdot$: $R$ $\times$ Hom$_{\mathbb{Z}}(A, B)$ $\longrightarrow$ Hom$_{\mathbb{Z}}(A, B)$ where $(r, \varphi)$ $\longmapsto$ $\varphi(r\cdot -)$. This map makes Hom$_{\mathbb{Z}}(A, B)$ indeed an $R-$module. Similarly, Hom$_{\mathbb{Z}}(R, B)$ is also an $R-$module and thus Hom$_{R}(A, \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R, B))$ an $R-$module. Now consider the map:
\begin{align*}
     \alpha: \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A, B) &\longrightarrow \text{Hom}_{R}(A, \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R, B))\\
     \varphi & \longmapsto (a \longmapsto (f_a := \varphi(-\cdot a) : R \longrightarrow B))\\
 \end{align*} and consider another map:
\begin{align*}
     \beta: \text{Hom}_{R}(A, \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R, B)) & \longrightarrow \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A, B)\\
     (a\longmapsto f_a: R \longrightarrow B) &\longmapsto f_a(1_{R})
 \end{align*} Now $\alpha \circ \beta$ and $\beta \circ \alpha$ are obviously identity maps and thus they are isomorphic as $R-$modules.